# Update Navigation Property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I am a new at depth of the Entity Framework 
I have just wondered why Entity Framework doesn't save changes especially the navigation property although all other properties are already updated
Please I want simple explanation

This is My Service Class

```
public  class ProductsService
{
    AppDbContext _Context;
    public ProductsService()
    {
        _Context = new AppDbContext();
    }

    public Product GetProduct(int id)
    {
        return _Context.Products.Include(p=>p.Category).Where(pro =>pro.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public void UpdateProduct(Product product)
    {
        _Context.Entry(product).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        _Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(NewCategoryViewModel pro,int Id)
{
    CategoriesService ser = new CategoriesService();
    var NewProduct = ProService.GetProduct(Id);
    var NewCat = ser.GetCategory(pro.CategoryId);
    NewProduct.Description = pro.Description;
    NewProduct.Name = pro.Name;
    NewProduct.Price = pro.Price;
    NewProduct.Category = NewCat;

    ProService.UpdateCategory(NewProduct);
    return RedirectToAction("ProductTable");
}
```

I have tried this and it works fine

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(NewCategoryViewModel pro,int Id)
{

    using (var Context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var NewProd = Context.Products.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.Id == Id);
        var Cat = Context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(cat => cat.Id == pro.CategoryId);
        Context.Entry(NewProd).State = EntityState.Modified;
        NewProd.Name = pro.Name;
        NewProd.Description = pro.Description;
        NewProd.Price = pro.Price;
        NewProd.Category = Cat;
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and for UpdateCategory

```
public void UpdateCategory(Category category)
{
    using (var Context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        Context.Entry(category).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Why the first one Not work
I know may be the problem in the state of the navigation property

Comment: Is `ProductsService` registered as Singleton or as Scoped? If it is a singleton, the data context is not designed to be long-lived. Reusing it over multiple operations is a mistake in your design. In addition I would use DI for `public ProductsService()` aswell.

Comment: mmmmmm, I will try it , but why the scalar property is updated ??

Comment: I will try Scope, I  am  wondering why the only Complex type is not Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created the `DbContext` inside `ProductService` and you created a new Context inside:

```
public void UpdateCategory(Category category) 
{ 
    using (var Context = new AppDbContext()) 
    { 
        Context.Entry(category).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; 
        Context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

-> you use two different `DbContext`'s together (which can cause problems with change tracking)!

**Solution:**
Try to use DependencyInjection for all `DbContext`'s instead of creating them locally to prevent problems with change tracking.

Comment: You are a brilliant man , Actually I Used DI and the navigation property is now updated , Really I am a grateful for you , you are the first person help me in StackOverFlow , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using .add() instead of .entry(). 
.add() will also track other reachable entities.

documentation can be found here:
[entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am using EF 6 not core